# Creating New Modules in Saga GIS

Tags: saga, library

I have recently started development with SAGA and have run into some difficulties.

I have checked out the svn code base and have successfully compiled in VS-10 (except the project ViGrA).

Now I just want to create a new project and begin my development. I already have a project with some modules. I have checked the entries for them in the required MLB_interface.cpp. The project was supposed to be ready for a batch build, so I just added it as an existing project to the full saga solution.

When I build this new project I get errors like:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
>   public: static class CSG_String __cdecl CSG_String::Format(unsigned
>   short const *,...)" (__imp_?Format@CSG_String@@SA?AV1@PEBGZZ)

for all of my module cpp/obj files.

Comment: Check if you are linking to saga_api.lib

Comment: Yes, I am using saga_api.lib. But I think it is getting linked properly, because I can see its path in the Additional Include Directories. These error msgs start when it tries to create my dll.

Comment: Hi Johan, it would be very nice if you can describe or point me to some resource which describes how to add a new module project to Saga in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to create new Saga modules inside visual studio and add them to the Saga GUI.

I scratched my existing project(above) and began afresh!

1. Under the "saga.vc10.sln" which I got from the svn checkout I added a new Empty C++ Project.
2. Next I merged/overwrote this new .vcxproj file with the .vcxproj file from an existing Saga Library (climate tools etc...). This is a xml file, carefully copy most of the configuration properties into to the new empty .vcxproj file. You have to be extra careful when you come to the Compile and Include s in the xml. Here define **your** to be compiled/included files (or leave it empty and create these files using the solution explorer of VS).
3. When you copy the properties from an existing to your own, you might notice there are the some relative paths to the saga core and other libraries for Debug/Release Win32/x64.
   Change these relative paths namely 
   a. *Output Directory*
   b. *Additional Include Directories*
   c. *Additional Library Directories*
   from the properties page of your project and provide the Absolute path. (e.g. **E:\Dev\saga\saga-gis\bin\saga_vc_$(Platform)\modules** instead of **......\bin\saga_vc_$(Platform)\modules**)

Write your module compile and deploy and enjoy!!

**Please post if you know of a better way or if this did not work for you!**

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do it is to create a directory under the tools, for example.

That is a separate section for your functions and name of the module. let's say it is "something".

Under that directory for example open another one with name something_tools.

Under that create three file (see other modules) 1) MLT_INTERFACE.cpp 2) something.cpp 3) something.h

These files should be filled with classes and at least the execute function (see others for example). Interface also be edited.

Now go back to your module directory and create CMakeList.txt and add the something_tool to it.

Now, go back to src root and run the cmake again.

It will create and link everything for you and prepare a sln file for your module.

Just open your sln and have a happy dev!